# I'm trying to add Stipe payment using gform_after_submission Hook in Gravity form but redirection is not working

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

I have written this following script for my custom pluign to add a stripe payment after successfully submitted the form, Everything seems like working but it's not redirecting to me the checkout page. ( if i use print_r function to check the checkout url by $res->url variable it's working fine. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
add_action('gform_after_submission', function($entry) {

        $my_API_KY = 'dfsdfasdfasdfadsfdsfdsfadsfdsfdf'; // dummy api 

    // setup Stripe payment
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( $my_API_KY ) );


        $res = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [
                [
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'unit_amount' => 2000,
                    'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Example Product',
                    ],
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'https://siteurl.com/succ',
            'cancel_url' => 'https://siteurl.com/error',
            ]);
    // if we print_r($res->url) we can see the url

    wp_redirect($res->url);
    exit;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing exit; to exit();